# Play Games Services, Getting profile info of other players connected in real-time multiplayer game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

Has anybody tried this out? Can we implement this using BaseGameUtils library? If not how do i accomplish this stuff. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean get their in-game profiles? You might be able to do it using [GamesClient](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient).

Comment: It have found out that it's against their policy, in a real time multiplayer players are kept anonymous